# Is this bug in Zend_Tool_Project_Profile_Resource_Container::hasChildren()?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend Framework 1 has class Zend_Tool_Project_Profile_Resource_Container with method hasChildren(). The code is:

```
public function hasChildren()
{
    return (count($this->_subResources > 0)) ? true : false;
}
```

but count() returns '1' for any value that is not countable except for 'NULL' which gives '0'. `$this->_subResources > 0` will never return 'NULL' so `count($this->_subResources > 0)` will always return '1'. As a result method will always return 'TRUE'. Am i correct or missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You are right. if you wish, can create a PR to [zend](http://%20%20%20%20%20https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/136735e776f520b081cd374012852cb88cef9a88/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Profile/Resource/Container.php#L385)

It should be

```
public function hasChildren()
{
    return (count($this->_subResources) > 0) ? true : false;
}
```